# Didn't find class on path: DexPathList (Dynamic Feature Module)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, dynamic-feature-module

In the `MainApplication` I have override `MainApplication: SplitCompatApplication()`

In the `MainActivity` also registered `SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener` and tested the logic flow and seems that everything is working correct.

Note: The app contains also some other `Dynamic Feature Modules` and everything is also working correctly.

Ex. When I try to show a fragment from other dynamic feature modules everything is working correctly like in below code:

```
iperf = iperf ?: fm.fragmentFactory.instantiate(
                                    ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(),
                                    "com.******.app_advanced_tools_feature.fragments.iperf_feature"
                                ) as iperf_abstract
                                ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, iperf!!, "iperf")
                                ft.addToBackStack("iperf")
                                ft.commit()
```

The issue that I have is when adding another `DFM` and trying to show `Activity` instead of `Fragment` and it always fails with `ClassNotFoundException`

So, this code doesn't work:

```
val activity = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("com.*******.second_feature.activity.MainActivity")
                        startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, activity::class.java))
```

The `DFM` is found and loaded correctly from `SplitInstall` since it goes through

```
if (splitInstallManager.installedModules.contains("module_name")) {

    fun onSuccessfulLoad(moduleName: String, toolName: String)
}
```

Also, tried almost everything but nothing helped me. If anyone have any idea or maybe know any solution that would be great.